# snmp trap listener no message receiving

Tags: c#, snmp-trap, sharp-snmp, .net-4.7.1, snmpsharpnet

So i'm building a snmp trap receiver to receive snmp trap messages.
i'm using the sharpsnmp-net package from lexstudios aswell as the sample.engine with pipline from github.
I'm creating a simple wpf application to just show messages on screen for testing all in .net 4.7.1.

So for the listening part i roughly used the sample snmpd.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private SnmpEngine _engine;
        private const string StrAllUnassigned = "All Unassigned";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            var store = new ObjectStore();
            store.Add(new SysDescr());
            store.Add(new SysObjectId());
            store.Add(new SysUpTime());
            store.Add(new SysContact());
            store.Add(new SysName());
            store.Add(new SysLocation());
            store.Add(new SysServices());
            store.Add(new SysORLastChange());
            store.Add(new SysORTable());
            store.Add(new IfNumber());
            store.Add(new IfTable());

            var users = new UserRegistry();
            users.Add(new OctetString("neither"), DefaultPrivacyProvider.DefaultPair);
            users.Add(new OctetString("authen"), new DefaultPrivacyProvider(new MD5AuthenticationProvider(new OctetString("authentication"))));
            if (DESPrivacyProvider.IsSupported)
            {
                users.Add(new OctetString("privacy"), new DESPrivacyProvider(new OctetString("privacyphrase"),
                                                                             new MD5AuthenticationProvider(new OctetString("authentication"))));
            }

            if (AESPrivacyProviderBase.IsSupported)
            {
                users.Add(new OctetString("aes"), new AESPrivacyProvider(new OctetString("privacyphrase"), new MD5AuthenticationProvider(new OctetString("authentication"))));
                users.Add(new OctetString("aes192"), new AES192PrivacyProvider(new OctetString("privacyphrase"), new MD5AuthenticationProvider(new OctetString("authentication"))));
                users.Add(new OctetString("aes256"), new AES256PrivacyProvider(new OctetString("privacyphrase"), new MD5AuthenticationProvider(new OctetString("authentication"))));
            }

            var getv1 = new GetV1MessageHandler();
            var getv1Mapping = new HandlerMapping("v1", "GET", getv1);

            var setv1 = new SetV1MessageHandler();
            var setv1Mapping = new HandlerMapping("v1", "SET", setv1);

            var getnextv1 = new GetNextV1MessageHandler();
            var getnextv1Mapping = new HandlerMapping("v1", "GETNEXT", getnextv1);

            var v1 = new Version1MembershipProvider(new OctetString("public"), new OctetString("public"));

            var membership = new ComposedMembershipProvider(new IMembershipProvider[] { v1 });
            var handlerFactory = new MessageHandlerFactory(new[]
            {
                getv1Mapping,
                setv1Mapping,
                getnextv1Mapping
            });

            var pipelineFactory = new SnmpApplicationFactory(new RollingLogger(), store, membership, handlerFactory);
            _engine = new SnmpEngine(pipelineFactory, new Listener { Users = users }, new EngineGroup());
            _engine.ExceptionRaised += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.ToString());

            InitializeComponent();

            txtIp.Text = @"162"; //port to receive snmp trap
            cmbIp.Items.Add(StrAllUnassigned);
            foreach (IPAddress address in Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty).AddressList.Where(address => !address.IsIPv6LinkLocal))
            {
                cmbIp.Items.Add(address);
            }
            cmbIp.SelectedIndex = 0;


        }

        public void StartListeners()
        {
            try
            {
                _engine.Listener.ClearBindings();
                int port = int.Parse(txtIp.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                /*
                if (cmbIp.Text == StrAllUnassigned)
                {
                    if (Socket.OSSupportsIPv4)
                    {
                        _engine.Listener.AddBinding(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
                    }

                    if (Socket.OSSupportsIPv6)
                    {
                        _engine.Listener.AddBinding(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, port));
                    }

                    _engine.Start();
                    if (_engine.Active)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Engine activated");
                    }
                    return;
                }
                */
                IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(cmbIp.Text);
                if (address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    if (!Socket.OSSupportsIPv4)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(Listener.ErrorIPv4NotSupported);
                        return;
                    }

                    _engine.Listener.AddBinding(new IPEndPoint(address, port));
                    _engine.Listener.MessageReceived += Listener_MessageReceived;
                    _engine.Start();
                    if (_engine.Active)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Engine activated");
                    }
                    return;
                }

                if (!Socket.OSSupportsIPv6)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Listener.ErrorIPv6NotSupported);
                    return;
                }

                _engine.Listener.AddBinding(new IPEndPoint(address, port));
                _engine.Start();

                

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception has been thrown in start: " + ex);
            }
        }

        private void Listener_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("message received");
        }

        private void StopListeners()
        {
            _engine.Stop();
            _engine.Dispose();
        }       

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //send trap 
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            Messenger.SendTrapV1(
                new IPEndPoint(ip, 162),
                IPAddress.Loopback, // here should be IP of the current machine.
                new OctetString("public"),
                new ObjectIdentifier(new uint[] { 1, 3, 6 }),
                GenericCode.ColdStart,
                0,
                0,
                new List<Variable>());

        }

        private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            try
            {
                StartListeners();
            }
            catch (PortInUseException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Port is already in use: " + ex.Endpoint, @"Error");
            }
        }

        private void stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_engine.Active)
            {
                try
                {
                    _engine.Listener.MessageReceived -= Listener_MessageReceived;
                    StopListeners();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("exception in stop: " + ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So to receive snmp trap messages you also got to send one.
I have got a textbox with port number combobox with ip address.
a send trap button and start and stop button.

Send a trap works perfectly i can verify in wireshark i do have a snmp packet however icmp answer with port unreachable which means no one is listening.-> issue 1

When activating the engine i don't have any errors but regarding the icmp i checked in cmd with command : netstat -an to check if something was listening on port 162 but bad luck.

How can i verify the engine is working and or something is listening?
I subscribed to the message_received event but i don't receive anything which could lead to the fact that no one is listening.

And last but not least when I press the stop button i do get a socketexception, but don't receive any of my own messages from try catch loops -> Should I assume this is in the package?

How to solve this problem. I want just to receive snmpv1 trap messages and the store them in a datatable so far.

Comment: The easiest way is to add a timer and stop timer in Listener_MessageReceived.  Then if timer elapses you have an error that you can report.

Comment: You have to check snmptrapd, not snmpd.

Comment: @lexLi there is not program file in that folder just a .config file a properties folder and cproj file but nor program.cs file for example.

Comment: Clone the repo and open the solution file in Visual Studio please. A waste of time if you do otherwise.